# How to repeat values entered DTMF

Tags: twilio

I am trying to write some TwiML where the user will enter the phone number through keypad and I want to respond back and repeat the number they entered.

```
<Response>
    <Gather input="speech dtmf" finishOnKey="#" timeout="4" numDigits="5" action="https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EHb45a578e1b6a7a33187bb7e72f721dd1" method="GET">
        <Say>Please enter your number</Say>     
   </Gather>
  <Say>You entered: {Digits}</Say>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you use `<Gather>` you set an `action` attribute to a URL. Once the `<Gather>` has recorded the user's response it will make a new HTTP request to that `action` URL and it will not continue the current TwiML. So, in your example, the last `<Say>` won't be used.

It looks like you have set your `action` URL to a TwiML Bin. With TwiML Bins you can do some template interpolation based on the incoming request parameters. The parameter containing the digits the user pressed will be `Digits`.

So, what you need is a new TwiML Bin that just has the second `<Say>` from your example and use that TwiML Bin as the `action` URL.

```xml
<Response>
  <Say>You entered: {Digits}</Say>
</Response>
```

If you want to move beyond TwiML Bins, then you will need to write an application that can receive the webhook requests from Twilio, parse the response and read the `Digits` parameter (or the `SpeechResult` parameter, as you have "speech" in your `input` attribute too).